# Installing Ubuntu (Dual Boot) with MAC OS 10.9.2

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, mac, macosx

Can anyone could point me in the right direction for installing Ubuntu (the latest version...14.something) to dual boot alongside my existing  MAC OS 10.9.2?

I just want to make sure I do it right. Thanks!

Comment: What OS you already have installed? Do you have UEFI or BIOS motherboard?

Comment: I have Mac OS 10.9.2. I also have the Ubuntu iso on my USB drive which is plugged in.

Comment: Macs are a bit different. http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/ AND: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ The author of those links often is in this forum.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro

Comment: Follow the instructions at [Macbook Air - how to install a dual bootable Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/462360/macbook-air-how-to-install-a-dual-bootable-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to partition your hard drive to dual boot your pc. This is an excellent tutorial on how to dual boot your computer.
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html
It should walk you through everything on how to correctly install whatever other operating system you are interested in installing. Hope it helps!
Matt

Answer (score 0):

No one bothered to ask you which Mac you own. Steps for one Apple Machine may not work with another. To be safe, visit https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/CommunityHelpPages to find a guide suited to your machine.