# Macbook Air - how to install a dual bootable Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, configuration, macbook, macosx

On my Macbook Air 10.9.2 without crashing the current setup, how can i install as dual boot: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ? (can anyone please advise some step by step please)

Comment: I don't, but there are already a lot of questions devoted to this very subject: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=dual+boot+mac+ubuntu (and try apple.se as well -> http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=dual+boot+ubuntu). I'd suggest reading through these before anything else.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Download the [refind binary zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/) on OS X
2. Unpack it and run `install.sh` (on OS X)
3. Use OS X Disk Utility to resize your HFS+ partition

   - Create a partition for Ubuntu (create two partitions if you want a swap partition). Choose any partition type (it does not matter because you will overwrite them later).
4. Download [Ubuntu 14.04 amd64 iso image](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) and [write it to a USB flash drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)
5. Reboot and hold <kbd>option</kbd> key after you hear the bell, to start Startup Manager
6. Insert USB drive and select it. Ubuntu 14.04 installer will start.
7. At partitioning stage:

   - Select manual partitioning
   - Select the partition that you created in Disk Utility as your `/` (and set up swap if you created a partition for it)
8. At Grub install stage, Grub will detect an EFI system and install a boot loader to the EFI partition on `/dev/sda1`
9. At end of install, remove USB drive and reboot
10. Refind will load and show you the option of booting OS X or Ubuntu. Choose Ubuntu.

Comment: I must do manually that Disk resize first? Can the Ubuntu image not do it later with automatic settings cause this is a tricky and risky part. if i make mistake here, i think OSX will be screwed.

Comment: Do you have some screen shot how the partition should be made exactly (so that no risk involved)

Comment: The Ubuntu installer can not automatically repartition an OS X drive. It can manually repartition it, but it is probably a little safer to resize a HFS+ partition using Apple's tool. As far as I know, Disk Utility will not allow you to make a Mac unbootable. The partition layout is very simple, here is an example for a 128GB drive - the specific partition sizes depend on how you want to divide the drive between Linux and OS X: **Part1** fat32 200MB EFI  
**Part2** hfs+ 46GB Macintosh HD  
**Part3** fat32 66GB Ubuntu
(you could just leave Part3 unallocated and create it in Ubuntu installer)

Comment: Do i have to use amd64 iso image of Ubuntu for MacBook Air? Or its the 64 iso image? MacBook Air is also using intel cpu i5

Comment: Installed - but the wireless network card is not detected by Ubuntu 14.04 no internet on the Ubuntu

Comment: You probably need Broadcom firmware, see [WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx). Ubuntu is not allowed to distribute the Broadcom firmware, so you have to manually install it. Easiest way is to get internet access on the Mac first: connect your laptop to a USB ethernet or phone with USB tethering (on Android enable it at _Settings>Tethering & portable hotspot>USB tethering_), connect to internet, then do `apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`. If you can not get internet, download the package, transfer it on USB drive, and `dpkg -i`.

Comment: @bain hows the battery life on Macbook Air with Ubuntu?

Comment: @RohitKaradkar Sorry I don't really know - I use AC most of the time.

Comment: @bain suggestion from any of your friend / colleague would be nice. owning a Macbook Air is quite rare in INDIA

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 16.04 as mentioned in this guide. After installing Ubuntu is directly getting booted. For Mac I have to  press OPTION key then select Mac disk. Not sure why refind menu is not coming first place.

Answer (score 6):

Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Good for you for being open to discovering the awesomeness of Linux!

---

**For convenience, here's a [direct link](http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/16.04/release/) to the Kubuntu x64 ISO**

FYI: The 64-bit version has "AMD" in the name simply because AMD created the modern x64 architecture as we know it. I *think* Intel still leases x64 from AMD...

You **do not** need a Mac-specific image, and you **definitely** want the x64 version.

---

## Backup, backup, backup!

No matter how many people have successfully installed Ubuntu alongside OSX, there is still a very real possibility of losing everything on your hard disk, so please, do the prudent thing and make a full backup before proceeding!

---

## Note: You need to install `rEFInd` to get a boot menu on startup.

Here's a guide on how to do that, taken from the How-To-Geek:

> rEFInd is a boot manager that will allow you to choose between Mac OS
>   X, Linux, Windows, and other operating systems when you boot your
>   computer. Installing rEFInd makes the dual-boot process easier. (Some
>   older how-to’s will instruct you to use rEFIt, but it’s no longer
>   maintained. rEFInd is a currently maintained boot manager based on
>   rEFIt.)
>
> [Full-disk encryption](http://www.howtogeek.com/184675/how-to-encrypt-your-macs-system-drive-removable-devices-and-individual-files/) causes problems with rEFIt, so you’ll need to
>   disable full-disk encryption or [do some extra work](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#wde) before installing
>   rEFInd.
>
> First, visit the [rEFInd page on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/) and click the Download
>   button to download the latest `refind-bin-[version].zi`p file. Open a
>   Terminal window by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and, typing *Terminal*, and
>   pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag and drop the `install.sh` file from the downloaded
>   zip file into the terminal window and press Enter to run it.
>
> [image]
>
> Shut down your Mac — a full shut down, not a restart — and boot it
>   back up again. You should see the rEFInd boot manager screen.
>
> [image]

---

## Now for the actual install:

While the ISO is downloading, use Disk Utility to [partition your HDD](http://www.geek.com/apple/how-to-partition-a-mac-hard-drive-1482555/). Make sure to leave the partition you create as "Free Space". (No filesystem)

[image]

After you download the ISO, [burn it to a blank DVD](http://lifehacker.com/251758/mac-tip--how-to-burn-an-iso-or-dmg-file-to-disc).

If you'd like to burn it to a USB stick instead, see: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Next, hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key while hitting the power button. Continue to hold it down until you get the boot device selection menu. Then you want to choose "EFI Boot". It will show a picture of a DVD if you burned it to a DVD, and it will show a picture of a drive if you burned it to a USB stick.

[image]

After the installer loads, select the "Install Ubuntu" option, and then select "Install Alongside Mac OSX". Hopefully, it will automatically install to the partition you left as "Free Space" earlier.

[image]

After it installs, shut down and remove the installation media. Then reboot, and cross your fingers. Hopefully you'll see this:

[image]

## If after installing your Wi-Fi doesn't work:

Then you should post a new question on this site, including the version of Ubuntu you installed, whether you have a working Ethernet port, and the output of these two terminal commands:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
rfkill list all
```

And I'm sure Pilot6 or Chili555 will be glad to assist you! Make sure you add the [wireless](/questions/tagged/wireless) tag!

Comment: I just installed Xubuntu 16.04 on my MBP, everything went smoothly but the Wifi didn't install by default.  I also needed to reinstall `refind` after installing Xubuntu.  I had to run `sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms` to install the Broadcom drivers.  Your instructions worked like a charm.  +1