# Macbook air 4-2 Trusty Tahr post install script

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, mac, battery

When looking at the [macbook air 4-2 install guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir4-2), there is a reference to a post install script. This wiki seems outdated, so I didn't want to run the script after I'd installed Trusty Tahr. I'm mainly interested in the GPU power save parts of the script, as I'd like to maximize battery life.

Should I run this script?

If I only want to run the GPU power saving parts, is that a good idea?

Are there other resources (or perhaps other scripts) that I can run to help maximize battery life?

Answer (score 0):

That page and script seem to be about Ubuntu 12.04. The script adds lots of PPAs that are not relevant for 14.04. So, no, do not use it for 14.04.

Comment: I was unable to find any documentation regarding 14.04 on my macbook air. Any chance there's something I missed beyond the aforementioned link?

Comment: There is a very short install guide in answer to question [Macbook Air - how to install without crashing the OSX a dual bootable Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/462360/macbook-air-how-to-install-without-crashing-the-osx-a-dual-bootable-ubuntu-14). In general, Macbooks with Intel graphics are well supported by Linux now. The only remaining issue is Broadcom wifi not working sometimes on the installer, which is a pain because you can not connect to the net to download the working driver. Connecting the wifi on a phone or separate USB wifi/ethernet adaptor will work.