# Mac OS Big Sur - Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I want to dual boot with Ubuntu, but when I open disk utility and try to make MS-DOS(FAT) partition for Ubuntu, appears error and converts to APFS...
I have Mac OS Big Sur

Comment: Sounds like you need to resize your Mac OS partition, and make a new partition, but not format it until Ubuntu installation. See here: [Macbook Air - how to install a dual bootable Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462360/macbook-air-how-to-install-a-dual-bootable-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

I had High Sierra and did a Dual Boot by downloading the ISO file then partitioning at least 100 GB as DOS it might UN-mount and not be usable within the Mac OS (grayed out) but it will be available when you boot into the manager with the boot-able CD. Also please don't forget to partition for the swap file as well 4GB should be okay for that.